# Vaadin Login view Chrome not save password

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin

Update:
If I disable https redirection its works, can you help me what I am doing wrong with redirection?
application.prioerties:

```
server.http.port=8080
## SSL
server.port=443
```

Redirect:

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityCollection;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
public class HttpsConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

//  @Value("${server.port2}") // Defined in application.properties file
//  int httpPort = ;

//  @Value("${server.port}") // Defined in application.properties file
//  int httpsPort =;

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("server.http.port")));
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort( Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("server.port")));
        return connector;
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RequestUtil requestUtil;

    @Autowired
    private VaadinDefaultRequestCache vaadinDefaultRequestCache;

    @Autowired
    private ViewAccessChecker viewAccessChecker;

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    ReportService reportService;

    public static final String LOGOUT_URL = "/";

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

//      super.configure(http);

//      

        http.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(requestUtil::isFrameworkInternalRequest);
        // nor with endpoints
        http.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(requestUtil::isEndpointRequest);

        // Ensure automated requests to e.g. closing push channels, service
        // workers,
        // endpoints are not counted as valid targets to redirect user to on
        // login
        http.requestCache().requestCache(vaadinDefaultRequestCache);

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
        // TODO LOCAL HOST ENABLE AND ADMIN
        // .hasIpAddress(LOGOUT_URL , hasROle

        ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry urlRegistry = http
                .authorizeRequests();

        // Vaadin internal requests must always be allowed to allow public Flow
        // pages
        // and/or login page implemented using Flow.
        urlRegistry.requestMatchers(requestUtil::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll();
        // Public endpoints are OK to access
        urlRegistry.requestMatchers(requestUtil::isAnonymousEndpoint).permitAll();
        // Public routes are OK to access
        urlRegistry.requestMatchers(requestUtil::isAnonymousRoute).permitAll();
        urlRegistry.requestMatchers(getDefaultHttpSecurityPermitMatcher()).permitAll();

        // all other requests require authentication
        urlRegistry.anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Enable view access control
        viewAccessChecker.enable();

        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, LOGOUT_URL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        /*
         * auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people").groupSearchBase
         * ("ou=Budapest,ou=Hungary,ou=Users,ou=Company_OU,dc=groupad1,dc=com").
         * contextSource()
         * .url("ldap:///dc=springframework,dc=org").and().
         * passwordCompare() .passwordEncoder(new
         * BCryptPasswordEncoder()).passwordAttribute("userPassword");
         */
        // Custom authentication provider - Order 1
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);

//       Built-in authentication provider - Order 2
//      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin@password")
//              // {noop} makes sure that the password encoder doesn't do anything
//              .roles("ADMIN") // Role of the user
//              .and().withUser("user").password("{noop}user@password").credentialsExpired(true).accountExpired(true)
//              .accountLocked(true).roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/*.png");
//      web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/*");
    }
}
```

I have a basic fresh Vaadin tutorial based login view (https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security)

EDIT: I think the main problem that the browsers think the login form is a simple form... and not a login form . eg: it pops up my email address for username and I click manage it brings me to chrome address form options and not the password...

My main problem is that Chrome or any other browser not ask to save the password after login.. and neither fill out the form even if its stored at the same host (eg: localhost:8080)
*The problem is in the login view, because the chrome work properly and store passwords others sites for me and for other test users .*

The other problem is that the following configure part is deprecated and I couldnt find the updated one, since all tutorial use this.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, LOGOUT_URL);
```

this function is deprecated and I do

```
@Route("login")
@PageTitle("Login | My App")
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    private final LoginForm login = new LoginForm();

    public LoginView() {
        addClassName("login-view");
        setSizeFull();
        setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);

        login.setAction("login");
        login.setForgotPasswordButtonVisible(false);

        add(new H1("My App"), login);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {
        // inform the user about an authentication error
        if (beforeEnterEvent.getLocation().getQueryParameters().getParameters().containsKey("error")) {
            login.setError(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Maven pom with versions:

```
   <properties>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
            <vaadin.version>23.3.0</vaadin.version>
        </properties>
    
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.5.4</version> -->
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </parent>
```

Comment: Which version of Vaadin are you using?

Comment: Vaadin 23.3.0 , I also updated the question with it.

Comment: In chrome - Settings > Autofill > Password Manager 
Check if Offer to save passwords option is switched on

Comment: I have no issues with that. Firefox and also 1Password work fine. But I use LoginOverlay. https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/login